# JenkinsX (JX) step promote-helm-release and promote-jx-promote fails

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, jenkins-x

I try to debug and issue in JenkinsX but is very dificult, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.

I have two problem with JenkinsX, in two steps.
promote-helm-release step I have the next error

```
releasing chart REPO_NAMPE
error: failed to create chart release in dir charts/REPO_NAME: failed to publish: failed to run 'curl --fail -sS -u admin:PASSWORD --data-binary @REPO_NAME-0.0.48.tgz http://jenkins-x-chartmuseum.jx.svc.cluster.local:8080/api/charts' command in directory 'charts/REPO_NAME', output: ''
```

But if I run the command

```
helm package chats/REPO_NAME
```

works well

In the next step promote-jx-promote I have the next error

```
Promoting app REPO_NAME version 0.0.55 to namespace jx-staging
error: failed to create pull request in dir /tmp/jx-git-2547125682: failed to commit changes in dir /tmp/jx-git-2547125682: failed to git commit initial code changes: failed to run 'git commit -m chore: promote REPO_NAME to version 0.0.55
```

I try to commit a change on the repository and then JX will create de PR on staging and production